# Open, help! Account don't work. Python

Tags: python, file, input, io

```
import sys
import time
import os
def typer(x):
    for i in x:
        print(i, end='')
        time.sleep(0.040)


def register():

    name = input('Create username: ')+'.txt'
    file = open(name, 'a')
    i = input("Create password: ")
    file.write(i+'\n')
    typer("Creating account...")

def login():
    user = input("Insert username: ")
    try:
        file = open(user, "r")
    except FileNotFoundError:
        print("Username\Password incorrect")
        sys.exit()
    pas = input("Enter password: ")
    try:
        file = open(user, 'r')
        if user == file:
            pasmatch = file.read(1)
            if pas == pasmatch:
                typer("Logging into your account...")
    except:
        print("Username\Passowrd i incorrect")
        sys.exit()



menu = True


while menu == True:
    menu = True
    print("What do you want to do?")
    print("1. Register")
    print("2. Login")
    ii = input("")
    if ii == "1":
        register()
    if ii == "2":
        login()
        menu = False
```

Help, I made this program so it makes a save file with your account details in it. But the login fuction is not working and i don't know whats wrong. Even though the usernames match it still says in incorect

Comment: `if user == file`? And then you read a single byte with `file.read(1)`? You should read the [official Python tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3.4/tutorial/index.html).

Comment: @DeliriousSyntax - No, that doesn't make sense either. A string won't be found in an unread *file object*.

Comment: @DeliriousSyntax - All you changed was the name of the reference to the file object. Why would that make any difference? And no, it doesn't work, because, again, there are no strings to be found in unread file objects.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

```
import sys
import time
import os
def typer(x):
    for i in x:
        print(i, end='')
        time.sleep(0.020)


def register():

    name = input('Create username: ')+'.txt'
    file = open(name, 'a')
    i = input("Create password: ")
    file.write(i+'\n')
    typer("Creating account...")

def login():
    user = input("Insert username: ")
    try:
        file = open((user+'.txt'), "r")  # line altered
    except FileNotFoundError:
        print("Username\Password incorrect")
        sys.exit()
    pas = input("Enter password: ")
    pas += '\n'  # line altered
    try:
        file = open((user+'.txt'), 'r')
        if (user+'.txt') == file.name:  # line altered
            pasmatch = file.read() # line altered, removed '1'
            if pas == pasmatch:
                typer("Logging into your account...")
    except:
        print("Username\Password i incorrect")
        sys.exit()



menu = True


while menu == True:
    menu = True
    print("What do you want to do?")
    print("1. Register")
    print("2. Login")
    ii = input("")
    if ii == "1":
        register()
    if ii == "2":
        login()
        menu = False
```

This should do it. I saw issues with the use of file objects as file names.
Please be sure to mark this as the solution if it helps. Thanks!

Answer (score -2):

I think for this block;

```
    file = open(user, 'r')
    if user == file:
        pasmatch = file.read(1)
        if pas == pasmatch:
            typer("Logging into your account...")
```

you meant something like:

```
    file = open(user, 'r')
    if pas == file.read(): #or maybe even if pas in file.read():
        typer("Logging into your account...")
```

without going into much detail, your initial code had a few problems with how you were equating things (`user == file` does not make any sense since `user` is a string and `file` is a fileObject) or how you were reading (`read(1)` only reads one byte).